# How to prevent Jmeter from stopping internet?

Tags: jmeter, performance

I am doing some benchmark testing. During this, I have to increase numbers of users, keeping ramp-up time 1 and loop count 1. 
First I started with 100 users it passed, then I put 500 users it failed, Jmeter stopped internet on my system I couldn't do surfing anymore, checking emails, opening play store, gmail etc, nothing worked and I had to restart computer to make it work again.

Now I have to try different set of users between 100-500 but if I keep restarting laptop it would be very difficult to test.

My laptop: Windows7 64 bit, 4CPUs, 2.7GHz, 8GB RAM
Error that I got in failed samples:

`Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException`

`Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to https://the-homepage-I-am-testing.net refused`

Comment: Did you try it more than one times? If yes did you get same result? Did your laptop disconnect internet again? I mean did you get the same result repeatedly?

Comment: Yes, for all your questions. I give exact scenarios 25 users, ramp-up time 1 sec, loop count 1, time duration 10mins. At 8th min I start get this exception.

Comment: And each time the internet gets disconnected? Is it possible that the website you're testing doesn't allow frequent requests from a single IP OR similar constraints? Just as a security measure may be!

Comment: I am sure security is not the case.

Comment: You're not running out of memory right? Not seeing an error in the console `JMeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Comment: Are you running tests against a site you do not own, manage, control or where you have direct written permission from those that own, manage or control.....such as any Google service, any Yahoo service, any Microsoft service, etc....?